# Compare Collection with the information in DB using EF and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want to inform the Receivers about new contracts we have this week. After I sent the Emails, the Information about sent contracts are stored in MS SQL Database.

To avoid that someone become the same Email about contract more than one time I perform this steps:

1. I have the Collection with new contracts as the input
2. I read the information from DB using Entity Framework about sent Emails
3. If the Emails was already sent I add new Instance to the sent Emails Collection

After that, I remove the contracts from input collection that are already in sent collection:

```
public Collection<Contract> GiveContractsThatWereNotSent(Collection<Contract> newThisWeekContracts)
{
   var contractsWereSent = new Collection<Contract>();

   using (var accountingEntities = new AccountingEntities())
   {
      foreach (Contract newContract in newThisWeekContracts)
      {
         bool found = (from sent in accountingEntities .Tbl_SentProtocol
                       where
                          sent.CONTRACT_NO == newContract.ContractNo
                          && sent.CONTRACT_NO_ALT == newContract.ContractNoAlt
                        select sent ).Any();

         if (found)
         {
            contractsWereSent.Add(newContract);
         }
      }
   }    

   foreach (Contract contract in contractsWereSent)
   {
      newThisWeekContracts.Remove(contract);
   }

   return newThisWeekContracts; 
}
```

Comment: You're doing `N` queries to the database, where `N = newThisWeekContracts.Count`. Would probably be *better* [citation needed] to do just one query with two `IN` clauses. On the other hand, having two `IN` clauses with thousands of items each would *probably* be not so great either and would require further restructuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several points:

- Write your code against *abstractions*. `Collection` is a specific *implementation*.

  - You don't need `newThisWeekContracts` to be specifically a `Collection`. I'd take in any `IEnumerable<Contract>` instead.
  - By returning a `Collection`, the caller can *add* to it, or *remove* from it, which probably isn't the intended behavior. I'd return an `IEnumerable<Contract>`, or, if adding/removing is ok, I'd return an `IList<Contract>` or `<ICollection<Contract>` (i.e. an *abstraction*, not a specific *implementation*).
- I like the descriptive naming, casing is correct and all, but the names read a little bit awkward still.

It looks like the number of queries can be reduced, haven't profiled this but I would think it consumes fewer resources; the main thing is combining `.Where()` with `.Any()` and `!.Any()` as needed:

```
public IEnumerable<Contract> GiveContractsThatWereNotSent(IEnumerable<Contract> newContracts)
{
    using (var entities = new AccountingEntities())
    {
        var sentContracts =
                   entities.Tbl_SentProtocol
                           .Where(sent => 
                                  newContracts.Any(contract => 
                                                   sent.CONTRACT_NO == contract.ContractNo
                                                && sent.CONTRACT_NO_ALT == contract.ContractNoAlt))
                           .ToList();

    }

    // ...
}
```

That gives you *sent contracts* (/ `contractsWereSent`), but that's not what you're after. Now you need to return the contracts in `newContracts` (/ `newThisWeekContracts`) that are *not* in `sentContacts`.

What you have here:

```
foreach (Contract contract in contractsWereSent)
{
    newThisWeekContracts.Remove(contract);
}
```

[Involves calling `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` on each `contract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132413%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which verifies whether `Contract` implements `IEquatable<T>`, otherwise uses overrides of `.Equals` and `.GetHashCode` if `Contract` overrides them, otherwise uses *reference equality*... which doesn't sound very neat, since if a contract is "equal" when its `ContractNo` and `ContractNoAlt` exists in `sendContracts` when comparing in `Tbl_SentProtocol`, then I'd use the same equality comparison when I want to "remove" items from the `newContracts`.

In fact, I wouldn't remove anything from `newContracts`. Keep inputs for inputs!

How about this?

```
IEnumerable<Contract> sentContracts;
using (var entities = new AccountingEntities())
{
    sentContracts = // trying to prevent horizontal scrolling...
        entities.Tbl_SentProtocol
                .Where(sent =>  
                       newContracts.Any(contract => 
                                        sent.CONTRACT_NO == contract.ContractNo
                                     && sent.CONTRACT_NO_ALT == contract.ContractNoAlt))
                .ToList();  
}

return newContracts.Where(contract => !sentContracts.Any(sent =>
                                        sent.CONTRACT_NO == contract.ContractNo
                                     && sent.CONTRACT_NO_ALT == contract.ContractNoAlt))
                   .ToList();
```

---

One more thing, the entities should be named so as to read like normal code - entity type `SentContract` can be mapped to table `tbl_SentProtocol`, and properties `ContractNumber` and `ContractAltNumber` can map to columns `CONTRACT_NO` and `CONTRACT_NO_ALT` ;)

Comment: thank you for the very good explanation :)  Upvote + Accept